# How to allow all frame ancestors with CSP header?

Tags: http, iframe, header, content-security-policy

I have a web app which I want to display in an iframe in web apps with different domains. Since I have added a content-security-policy header my app refuses to display in iframe. I saw that i need to add frame-ancestors options but all the examples I see are using specific domains. How can I allow it for all domains? Is "frame ancestors *;" enough? Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Briefly - yes, `*` allows any sources for iframe except `data:`.

Pls note that *frame-ancestors* [is not supported](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#directive-frame-ancestors) in the meta tag `<meta http-equiv='Content-Security-Policy' content="...">` (but looks like you use HTTP header to delivery CSP, so this warn not for you).

But if you really wish to allow all frame ancestors - more reliable not specify *frame-ancestors* directive at all, because for now Mozilla Firefox has some bugs with it.

PS: You did not attach print screen of errors in browser console - may be iframes was block by other reason than CSP?

**updated after exposed CSPs details**

```
<html>
  parent page issues CSP: default-src 'self';
  since frame-src omitted, it fallback to default-src and result be: frame-src 'self'

  <iframe src=''></iframe>
</html>
```

iframe is allowed with the same `scheme://host:port` as parent page loads.
'self' is tricky in that if parent loaded via HTTP:, iframe via HTTPS: will blocked in CSP2-browsers. CSP3-browsers [do upgrade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSP3/#changes-from-level-2) (see para 3) HTTP: to HTTPS:, so all OK.

If parent page issue `frame-ancestors *` policy, it means you allow to embed it into iframe to any another webpage.
*X-Frame-Options* HTTP header provide the same functionality, but [it's overridden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#wikiArticle) if frame-ancestor is issueed.

- frame-ancestor directive does not affects `<iframe>` embed into page who published this CSP. It affects where it allowed to embed this page.
- But `<iframe>` could publish its own CSP with rule `frame-ancestors domain1.com domain2.com` to restrict it embedding to other web-pages.

That's how it works. You could play with [test of frame-ancestors](https://csplite.com/csp/test221/#nocsp) to clarify details for different `<iframe src=/srcdoc=`.

Therefore if you embeds iframe from your own domain/subdomains, it's more safe to use:

`frame-ancestors 'self';`

or if you use subdomains:

`frame-ancestors http://example.com https://example.com http://*.example.com https://*.example.com;`

Comment: Actually there was no frame ancestors before and it got blocked. Interestingly, the error in console said that the site set x-frame-options to 'sameorigin' which was not true at all, but i think with the asterix everything is fine. (at least for now)

Comment: That's why I adds PS: - frame-ancestors rarely who adds. You have  X-Frame-Options HTTP-header issued somewhere. Change this header appropriate. Or use frame-ancestors - it overrides this header in supported browsers..

Comment: There was no x-frame-options anywhere :D

Comment: That's weird. CSP do not affect frames in absence sandbox/frame-src/frame-ancestors directives in it. What does the browser console say? There should be info why the iframe is blocked.

Comment: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' <analytics-url> 'nonce-somenonce'; object-src 'none'; connect-src 'self' <other-analytics-url; sandbox allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-scripts; base-uri 'self'; -  that was the csp before i added "frame-ancestors *"

The console said that the site set X-Frame-Options to 'sameorigin' but I actually removed it long time ago.

Comment: I have updated my answer to expose some details. If console said - this header is published somewhere. It leads browsers not support frame-ancestors could refuse to load iframes.

Comment: To clarify, could someone post exactly the format string between <head></head> of the frame-ancestors policy? If we cannot use <meta,,, what tag can we use instead?

Comment: The `frame-ancestors` directive is supported only in the Content Security Policy HTTP response header. Server have to publish this header along with iframe.